# How do you return every possible combination of 2 lists in python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to create a list of every possible combination between 2 lists of elements regardless of either list's size (they may or may not be identical lengths).

I've looked through itertools examples and searched stackoverflow but haven't found an exact example of what I'm looking for.

INPUT:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = [1, 2]
```

OUTPUT:

```
['a1-b1-c1', 'a1-b1-c2', 'a1-b2-c1', 'a1-b2-c2', 'a2-b1-c1', 'a2-b1-c2', 'a2-b2-c1', 'a2-b2-c2']
```

but again, `l1` can be any size and `l2` can be any size.  Don't care at all about formatting, just want the complete output.

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: @AnthonyKong permutations only takes 1 "element".  I don't want to submit 'ABC123' cause that'll also return AB, etc.  Let me know if I'm missing something

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.product` to generate all possible 3-combinations of `l2`, and then join each combination with `l1`.

```
from itertools import product

combs = product(map(str, l2), repeat=3)
['-'.join([x + y for x, y in zip(l1, c)]) for c in combs]
# ['a1-b1-c1', 'a1-b1-c2', 'a1-b2-c1', 'a1-b2-c2', 'a2-b1-c1', 'a2-b1-c2', 'a2-b2-c1', 'a2-b2-c2']
```

Comment: Minor note: I did initially hold back on using `product` as I wanted OP to try solving this problem themselves. Since the other answerers did not hold back, I decided to edit with the best solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This solution creates a template from `l1`: eg. `'a{}-b{}-c{}'`

```
from itertools import product
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = [1, 2]
template = "{}-".join(l1) + "{}"
[template.format(*c) for c in product(l2, repeat=len(l1))]
```

---

['a1-b1-c1', 'a1-b1-c2', 'a1-b2-c1', 'a1-b2-c2', 'a2-b1-c1', 'a2-b1-c2', 'a2-b2-c1', 'a2-b2-c2']

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.product` and list comprehensions to get the result you are after:

```
from itertools import product
result = ["-".join(y+str(z) for y, z in zip(l1, x)) for x in product(*[l2] * 3)]
```

I would like to note that approach does not produce any extra intermediate combinations.

Output:

```
['a1-b1-c1', 'a1-b1-c2', 'a1-b2-c1', 'a1-b2-c2', 'a2-b1-c1', 'a2-b1-c2', 'a2-b2-c1', 'a2-b2-c2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
['-'.join(map(''.join, zip(l1, c))) for c in product(map(str, l2), repeat=len(l1))]
```

This returns:

```
['a1-b1-c1', 'a1-b1-c2', 'a1-b2-c1', 'a1-b2-c2', 'a2-b1-c1', 'a2-b1-c2', 'a2-b2-c1', 'a2-b2-c2']
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please mark what you think is the best answer as accepted. (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)